# Two Donut Charts On The Same Page

Tags: d3.js, donut-chart

I'm teaching myself D3 via a few different websites, to help make my data look more interesting (of course!) and i feel that i have the basics down.

But i'm struggling to figure out how to put two donut charts on the same page. I want them to be exactly the same, other than the data and positioning.

I've included the code below, and would appreciate any help.

As i said, the code of how to get the charts will be the exactly the same, so hopefully i don't have duplicate too many items (and hopefully remove some bad practices that i've picked up).

Cheers,

George

```
Donut Chart 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Pie sort</title>
</head>

<style>

  text {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: white;
    text-anchor: middle;
 }

  .container1 {
     float: left;
 }

  .container2 {
    float: right;
 }

 </style>

 <body>


    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container1" id="svg1"></div>
    <div class="container2" id="svg2"></div>
    <script>

    var mentalHealth1 = [{
    City: 'Brighton',
    Percentage: 1.77
    }, {
    City: 'Bristol',
    Percentage: 1.16
    }, {
    City: 'Luton',
    Percentage: 1.04
    }, {
    City: 'Milton Keynes',
    Percentage: 0.93
    }, {
    City: 'Southampton',
    Percentage: 1.37
   }];

   var mentalHealth2 = [{
   City: 'Bradford City',
   Percentage: 1.22
   }, {
   City: 'Leeds',
   Percentage: 1.31
   }, {
   City: 'Liverpool',
   Percentage: 1.56
   }, {
   City: 'Manchester',
   Percentage: 1.41
   }, {
   City: 'Sheffield',
   Percentage: 1.24
   }];

   draw("svg1", mentalHealth1);
   draw("svg2", mentalHealth2);

   function draw(selector, data) {
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);

   var mentalHealthPie = d3.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
      return d.Percentage
   })
   .sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.City.localeCompare(b.City);
   });

  var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
     .innerRadius(150)
     .outerRadius(175);

  var arcData = mentalHealthPie(data);

  var svg = d3.select("#svg1")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 450)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)");

  var svg = d3.select("#svg2")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 450)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(400,200)");

  svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(arcData)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .style("fill", function(d) {
       return color(d.data.Percentage);
    })
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .attr('d', arcGenerator);
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's great that you asked about *best practices*. However, S.O. is not the best place for such a question. If you have a **working code** and you want to get advice about best practices, try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a lot of duplicated code if you wrap everything inside a function which accepts two arguments, the selector for creating the SVG and the data array, which are the only different elements when you compare your codes.

```
function draw(selector, data){
    //code here...
};
```

Then, you call it twice:

```
draw("svg1", mentalHealth1);
draw("svg2", mentalHealth2);
```

In this case, the HTML has two divs, with these IDs:

```
<div id="svg1"></div>
<div id="svg2"></div>
```

That way you have a [DRYer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code that you can call how many times you want.

Here is the demo:

```js
var mentalHealth1 = [{
  City: 'Brighton',
  Percentage: 1.77
}, {
  City: 'Bristol',
  Percentage: 1.16
}, {
  City: 'Luton',
  Percentage: 1.04
}, {
  City: 'Milton Keynes',
  Percentage: 0.93
}, {
  City: 'Southampton',
  Percentage: 1.37
}];

var mentalHealth2 = [{
  City: 'Bradford City',
  Percentage: 1.22
}, {
  City: 'Leeds',
  Percentage: 1.31
}, {
  City: 'Liverpool',
  Percentage: 1.56
}, {
  City: 'Manchester',
  Percentage: 1.41
}, {
  City: 'Sheffield',
  Percentage: 1.24
}];

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);

var mentalHealthPie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.Percentage
  })
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.City.localeCompare(b.City);
  });

var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(150)
  .outerRadius(200);

draw("svg1", mentalHealth1);
draw("svg2", mentalHealth2);

function draw(selector, data) {

  var arcData = mentalHealthPie(data);

  var svg = d3.select("#" + selector)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(250,250)")

  svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(arcData)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.Percentage);
    })
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .attr('d', arcGenerator);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg1"></div>
<div id="svg2"></div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Just two quick questions, how can i put the graphs in an in-line block with the code you suggested? As it's currently in a column? And how can i then add two smaller graphs below? By implementing more id's and creating an independent 'transform and translate' attribute for them? Cheers

Comment: Use CSS to make the divs side by side. Regarding your second question, you can add more parameters to control the size of the chart, for example.

Comment: Hi mate, i've played around with the code and implemented the changes. I've split it into two containers, which works, and i can float them left and right. But i can't get them on the same level?

Comment: Please, post this as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786520/multiple-d3-graphs-and-their-positioning - Thank you